# Pandas data frame grouping by loses the grouping function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (`glob_df`) which I am trying to group by by the `lga_abbreviated_name` field as below:

```
>>> glob_df.dtypes
lga_abbreviated_name     object
counts                    int64
update_date_time_date    object
dtype: object
>>> dg=glob_df.groupby('lga_abbreviated_name').aggregate({'counts':'sum'})
>>> dg.dtypes
counts    int64
dtype: object
```

I noticed that when I perform groupby operation, I lose the column `lga_abbreviated_name` in the aggregated dataframe.

How can I keep that column along with aggregated columns in the grouped dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`as_index` = False

```
dg=glob_df.groupby('lga_abbreviated_name', as_index=False).aggregate({'counts':'sum'})
```